# Out-of-tree build makefile without automake?

Tags: makefile

Consider the following dead-simple Makefile:

```
foo: foo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

And the following directory structure for `~/foo`:

```
Makefile
foo.c
```

How can I adjust the Makefile such that I can do something like:

```
/tmp$ make -f ~/foo/Makefile
cc -o foo /home/me/foo/foo.c
```

I have tried to use `$(srcdir)`, but that seems `automake`-specific. Is there any other similar variable?

Comment: Is `/home/me/foo` the same as `~/foo`? You want to call Make from `/tmp` and have it build the executable `/tmp/foo`, is that right?

Comment: @Beta `/home/me/foo` is indeed the same as `~/foo` in this example. Right, I want to be able to output binaries in the current working directory (`/tmp`) while having the source in a different directory (`/home/me/foo`).

Answer (score 3):

This will do it:

```
foo: /home/me/foo/foo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Or this:

```
foo: foo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

vpath %.c /home/me/foo
```

Or, if you don't want to hard-code the path into the makefile:

```
foo: foo.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

vpath %.c $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
```

Comment: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make/html_node/make_17.html suggests using `$(word $(words $(MAKEFILE_LIST)),$(MAKEFILE_LIST))`. https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Makefile-Basics.html says to use `$(srcdir)`, but it looks like srcdir isn't defined by make?

Comment: That first link pertains to an old version of Make; I don't know when `lastword` was implemented, but I think it's hands-down superior to `$(word $(words $(X), $(X))`. As for `srcdir`, I think it's meant to be a user-defined variable (i.e. `srcdir := /home/me/foo`) and not a variable maintained automatically by Make.